# How to preserve mime type in CUPS forwarding?

Tags: cups, mime-types, forwarding

I installed a small CUPS printer which accepts only `application/postscript` and converts this into a bitmap.
Using a generic postscript printer driver I can directly print to this device without problems.
Now the printer lives behind a server also running CUPS. There I configured the printer as a generic postscript printer.
The server handles other printers, too, for which it converts all incoming postscript to data in the printer's language. I want my printer to appear in the same way as the other printers installed on the server (server-ip/cups/my-printer/).

**Problem**: When I print postscript to the server's CUPS, it will convert the mime type from `application/postscript` to `application/vnd.cups-raw` without changing the data itself. My printer receives this as a file with mime type `vnd.cups-raw` which it cannot handle.

How can I tell the server's CUPS to simply forward postscript to my printer without touching the mime type?

**EDIT:** One solution would be to connect a specific server port to the IP of my printer so that all communication (two-way) is simply relayed, much like a proxy. But I imagine CUPS should be able to do that natively.